# Not able to get JSON file from resource folder using relative path

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, inputstream

I am trying to get a JSON file form my resource folder in the main method using relative path. The code works using absolute path but this breaks once I build a jar file from my project which is want I want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
// Read in database
db = Database.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("JSON/inhabitants.json").toExternalForm());
names = db.getAllNames();
```

Read calls a method in Database which uses a inputstream to read the file.

```
  public static Database read(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

    return gson.fromJson(reader, Database.class);
  }
```

The error I am getting is the following :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   file:/Users/timpelser/IdeaProjects/TurfApp/target/classes/JSON/inhabitants.json
>   (No such file or directory)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   Core.Database.read(Database.java:22)  at Main.main(Main.java:51)  ...
>   11 more

The file in directory `/Users/timpelser/IdeaProjects/TurfApp/target/classes/JSON/inhabitants.json`

does exist however so I have no idea what is going wrong.

Here is my folder structure (Maven basic structure):

[image: folder structure]

Is there a solution which will still able me to deploy it as a jar file ?

EDIT (25/09) : If I use getResourceAsStream instead of getResource, I am getting the following error :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.BufferedInputStream@4f8e5cde (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at Core.Database.read(Database.java:22)
at Main.main(Main.java:51)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Just for information, why are you putting json file in target folder? Target is build folder, and will be erased every time you do `mvn clean`

Comment: I did not do that on purpose, I just added the file to the resource folder and when building the artifacts it added it to the targets folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `getResourceAsStream` to read files from within the running jar (which contains the files within `src\main\resources`)!

Comment: I am getting a file not found exception using getResourcAsStream

Comment: I don't know which development environment you use. If you run it e.g. in Eclipse, then Eclipse should handle this call like it would have been from inside a jar but what's inside a jar? The lookup then goes to the classpath and `src\main\resources` have to be in the classpath! Please check if this is the case in your scenario. (in Eclipse right-click on `src\main\resources` -> "Build Path" -> "Use as Source Folder")

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, resources is set as default Resource folder

Comment: I don't know the exact names in IntelliJ but you've also to ensure that `src\main\resources` is within the classpath/source folder!

Comment: Euh I don't understand since the classpath is src/main/resources, or am I not understanding something ?

Comment: You can right click on any directory in your IntelliJ project, select "Mark Directory As...", and choose "Source Root". That director folder will change color from yellow to blue; IntelliJ considers all those directories to be in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: As you can see in the picture on my post this is already done on the java folder. Or should I mark another directory as Source root ?

Comment: Okay, this is the third and hopefully last time I'll try to explain to you, that you have to set the following directory as "Source Root" : **`src\main\resources`**. I've no idea why you talk about the java folder which I've never mentioned at any time. I'm sorry but if you don't read my answers then I won't explain it once more.

Answer (score 0):

Use This,

```
Resource resource = new classpathResource(json);

new ObjectMapper.readValue(resource.getInputStream(),Object.class);
```